# Why did my JSON data change?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to pass my json data `location` argument to `assignLocationValues` and `console.log` it. When i log `location.loc` it shows two values which look something like this: 4,2394, 5,3023. When i take a value from it like: `location.loc[1]` and log it. The value changes, instead of 5,3023 it becomes 1. What is happening?

Edit: figured it out. I really thought it was an array. So strange...............

```
$(document).ready(function() {
getLocation();

function getLocation() {

  $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(location) { 

    assignLocationValues(location.loc[0], location.loc[1], location.city, location.region, location.country );

    function assignLocationValues(lat, lon, city, region, country){

      console.log(location.loc);
      console.log(lat);
    };
  }, 'jsonp');
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

place it in a script tag at the bottom of the **body** tag (document.ready is yesterday's news)

```
function assignLocationValues(obj_location){

  var loc = obj_location;

  var _city = loc.city;
  var _country = loc.country;
  var _hostname = loc.hostname;
  var _ip = loc.ip;
  //....
  console.log(_ip);

};

function getLocation() {
  $.get("http://ipinfo.io/json", function(location) {
      assignLocationValues(location);
    });
}

getLocation();
```

Answer (score -1):

try this : http://jsbin.com/IDebUfu/1/edit?html,js,output

```
$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?", function(data) {
    var table_body = "";
    $.each(data, function(k, v) {
    table_body += "<tr><td>" + k + "</td><td><b>" + v + "</b></td></tr>";
    });
    $("#GeoResults").html(table_body);
});
```